# How to move things in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

i have been all day trying to learn tkinter but to no avail. All the information I found seems outdated and I have seen a thousand methods to move things but all of them stick to one side. I have written css  in less time than this.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
root.title('aaaa?')
root.geometry('400x300')
root.config(bg='#F2B33D')
frm = Frame(root, bg='#F2B33D')
frm.grid()
Label(frm, text="Hello World!").grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=100)
Button(frm, text="Not yet").grid(column=0, row=3)
Button(frm, text="Quit", command=root.destroy).grid(column=2, row=3)

frm.pack(expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

What I want to do with this failed code is to make to symmetrically position buttons on the inferior center and the label on the upper center, then, know if the user clicked to not yet button and store that in variable. I even made a cool drawing.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uralJ.png)
thanks